# How to limit user request once a year in php

Tags: php

I created a user who is allowed to request annual leave for only 28 days a year (January to December), So I want to restrict or limit a user to only 28 days once in a year from January to December, so if a user makes another request in between, should get an error.

Another issue, If a user chooses to start his leave maybe on 1 May 2021 as a startdate and wants to use only 10 days out of his 28 days, the enddate (requested) should be inserted automatically (based on his request) on the end date input field using date type (such as 10 May 2021).
This is what i have at the moment, only restrict a user not to exceed 28 days for the annual leave. Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
 <label>The entitled number of days for this leave:</label>
        <input type="number" name="duration"  size="4" required>
      </p>
      <p>
   
        <label>The number of days I am requesting out of 28 is:</label>
        <input type="number" name="requested" " size="4" required>
        <strong> </strong>
        <label>From:</label>
        <input type="date" name="startdate"  required>
        <label>To:</label>
        <input type="date" name="enddate"> <!-- this should be generated automatically-->
      </p>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    
    $_POST["duration"];
    
    if($_POST["duration"]>28){
        echo "You have exceed number of days for annual leave";
        }

..........

?>
```

Comment: do you have a database to use? you can use that to compare how many request the user already made for the year

Comment: I guess you are using a Database to register if user has taken leave earlier? Please show how and what information you store for users.

Comment: Yes I have database that stores users and leaves, the leave table captures the userid,startdate enddate, duration, type,requested and other information.I have an insert query that insert data from the form. I did omit other information, i am interested in those areas. Here is the sql ` $query1="INSERT INTO leaves(start,end,status,employee,payment,duration,requested,type,comments,address) VALUES('".$_POST["startdate"]."','".$_POST["enddate"]."','2','$id','".$_POST["payment"]."','".$_POST["duration"]."','".$_POST["requested"]."','1','".$_POST["comments"]."','".$_POST["address"]."')"; 
 }

Comment: Please can you clarify the question and relate it specifically to the programming challenges you have and not just the use case? Please refer to the [SO's guidelines on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)